# Update dynamic number in class name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, I'm trying to find a solution to my issue.

I have this html...

```
<p class="prodReview prodReviewsNN"></p>
```

... and a number replaces "NN" dynamically.

- The number can be anywhere from 0 to 5 and including decimals, such as 1.2, 3.5, etc.
- Single digit numbers doesn't have ".0" at the end.

What needs to be done though after "NN" gets replaced by a number...

1. Remove the decimal point if the number has one, for example 1.2 becomes 12.
2. If a number is single digit, such as 1 or 4, add a zero at the end, for example 10 or 40.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your work.

Comment: Javascript is a very capable language; you *really* don't need jQuery for this. And as @Soviut has asked, what have *you* tried?

Comment: @clabe45 it's best not to make technical recommendations since it distracts from the original problem. The OP may have other reasons to use jQuery beyond this particular problem.

Comment: @Soviut, I see, but it appears the OP is trying to rely on jQuery instead of thinking through the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this simple plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.replaceClass = function (pFromClass, pToClass) {
         pToClass = editDecimal(pToClass)  // DECIMAL MANIPULATION
        return this.removeClass(pFromClass).addClass(pToClass);
    };
}(jQuery)); 

function editDecimal(pToClass){
    var num = pToClass.split("prodReviews")[1]  // will get the NN part                 
    num = num* 10 
    pToClass = "prodReviews"+num
    console.log(pToClass)
    return pToClass 

}
```

Usage:

```
$('.prodReview').replaceClass('prodReviewsNN','prodReviews2');
$('.prodReview').replaceClass('prodReviewsNN','prodReviews3.2');
```

Before:

```
<p class="prodReview prodReviewsNN"></p>
```

After:

```
<p class="prodReview prodReviews20"></p>
<p class="prodReview prodReviews32"></p>
```

Comment: [user2428993](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428993/user2428993)    If a number is between 0 and 1 .. e.g. 
0.6  ... Should it  output [prodReviews6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428993/user2428993) or [prodReviews60](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428993/user2428993) ?????

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? why not store the number in the DOM Element?

anyway...

```
var num = 2;
document.querySelector('.prodReview').className = 'prodReview prodReviews'+num;
```

and next time when you need to rewrite the class...

```
var newNum = 5;

document.querySelector('.prodReview .prodReviews'+oldNum).className = 'prodReview prodReviews'+newNum;
```

but a better solution would be to store the number in the DOM

```
var n = 2;
document.querySelector('.prodReview').n = n;
```

and then get it using :

```
var needle = 5;

var element = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.prodReview')).filter(function(e){return e.n == needle})[0]
```